# How to update only one column icon in table in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I try to improve Table view by use angularjs only. (Without add/remove class)

Here is example:  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hB1yzCr16RAyDCdZwRKx?p=preview).

I want my table to be dynamic, it means that I don't know how many columns it has, therefore I use `ng-repeat`.

To that example I added:

```
$scope.headers = ['ProgramCode','ProgramGroup','EventCode','StartDate','FormalDate','LocCity','LocState','LocAddress', 'LocName','Price', 'LicenseeURL','GateKeeper_length','GateKeeperHTML','SeatsAreAvailable','LocLatitude','LocLongitude','EventType',"LocationUnivURL","UnivCourseNumber","UnivCourseType","UnivFaculty","Course_Type","cls"];
```

On start, instead `$scope.reverse = false;` I wrote `$scope.reverse = undefined;`

And now the header I can write like:

```
    <th ng-repeat="header in headers">{{ header }}
           <a ng-click="sort_by(header)">
             <i ng-class="{
                   'icon-sort':reverse == undefined,
                   'icon-chevron-up': reverse,
                   'icon-chevron-down': !reverse
                    }">
             </i>                                
            </a>
   </th>
```

I changed `sort_by` method that looks like:

```
 $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {   
  $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;   
 };
```

However, when I press on down/up button to activate sorter, it updates all icons in all columns like in followed example: [updated_Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nsopwka4UOekUAUU7E2U?p=preview)

Well, i have only one flag `reverse` for all columns. Do I need create list of flags or `angularjs` has other technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because they are all referencing the same `reverse` since you are setting it in the `ctrlRead` scope:

```
app.controller('ctrlRead', ['$scope', '$filter', 'Items', function($scope, $filter, Items) {

  ... 

  $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {  
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;  
  };

  ... 

}]);
```

You need to give each header its own place to store the reverse-information. There are at least two ways to do this. You can store it on the header objects themselves:

```
  $scope.sort_by = function(header) {  
    header.reverse = !header.reverse;  
  };
```

with the corresponding change in the HTML:

```
    <th ng-repeat="header in headers">{{ header }}
      <a ng-click="sort_by(header)">
        <i ng-class="{
            'icon-sort':header.reverse == undefined, 
            'icon-chevron-up': header.reverse, 
            'icon-chevron-down': !header.reverse 
        }"></i>                                     
      </a>
    </th>
```

You also need to change the headers from simple strings to objects so they can hold the extra information. I did this quick and dirtily by just mapping the array of strings to objects:

```
$scope.headers = ['ProgramCode','ProgramGroup','EventCode','StartDate','FormalDate','LocCity','LocState','LocAddress', 'LocName','Price', 'LicenseeURL','GateKeeper_length','GateKeeperHTML','SeatsAreAvailable','LocLatitude','LocLongitude','EventType',"LocationUnivURL","UnivCourseNumber","UnivCourseType","UnivFaculty","Course_Type","cls"];
$scope.headers =$scope.headers.map(function(h){return {title:h};});
```

[I've forked the plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wwKPXHpmIZGvzj1iHiXa?p=preview).

The second option is to introduce a new controller in the `ng-repeat` and moving the sorting stuff into that. Then each header will have their own controller and scope and therefore also their own `$scope.reverse`. Note that `ng-repeat` already introduces a new scope for each header, but it doesn't help you since your sort function is defined on the *outer* scope which is shared by all of them.

I recommend the first method for now though since it makes the sorting information easily available outside of the individual header scopes. With the second method the sorting information would only be available inside the individual header scopes, so you would need to do extra work to access it from in the rest of the table.